# Tic Tac Toe , Why am I getting the error non standard syntax use & to create a pointer to a member

Tags: c++

here is my main . I get the error for the part I am checking whether the game had a winner or not. the errors are referring to the if parts where i wanna check the returned data from chkwin method

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include "TicTacToe.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string choice = "";
        string name1 = "";
        string name2 = "";
        string change = "";
        int choice_num;
        TicTacToe game;

        cout << "Welcome to TicTacToe World!\n"
            << "In order to Start Please Enter the name of the first player\n\n";
        getline(cin, name1);

        cout << "\nGreat, Now Please Enter the name of the second player\n\n";
        getline(cin, 

name2);

        cout << "\nAwesome Let's Get Started!\n";

        do
        {
            cout << "\nPlease choose what do you want to do by entering the number of your choice\n"
                << "1.Start the game.\n"
                << "2.Change the names.\n"
                << "3.View Scores\n"
                << "4.Exit the Game :(\n\n";
            getline(cin, choice);

            if (choice == "1")
            {
                for (int i = 1; 1 <= 9; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        cout << "It's " << name1 << " Turn. Please Make Your move.";
                        cin >> choice_num;
                        cin.ignore();

                        game.setMove(choice_num, 1);
                        if (game.chkWin == 1)
                        {
                            cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
                        }
                        else if (game.chkWin == -1)
                        {
                            cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
                        }
                        else if (game.chkWin == 0)
                        {
                            cout <<"The Game is a Draw! ";
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "It's " << name1 << " Turn. Please Make Your move.";
                        cin >> choice;
                        cin.ignore();

            game.setMove(choice_num, 2);
                        if ( 1 == game.chkWin)
                        {
                            cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
                        }
                        else if (game.chkWin == -1)
                        {
                            cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
                        }
                        else if (game.chkWin == 0)
                        {
                            cout << "The Game is a Draw! ";
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            else if (choice == "2")
            {
                do
                {
                    cout << "\nwhich player do you want its name to be changed? (Enter 1 for the first, 2 for the second and 3 for both)\n";
                    getline(cin, change);
                    if (change == "1")
                    {
                        cout << "\nPlease Enter the new name for the player one.\n";
                        getline(cin, name1);
                    }
                    else if (change == "2")
                    {
                        cout << "\nPlease Enter the new name for the player two.\n";
                        getline(cin, name2);
                    }
                    else if (change == "3")
                    {
                        cout << "\nPlease Enter the new name for the player one.\n";
                        getline(cin, name1);

                        cout << "\nPlease Enter the new name for the player two.\n";
                        getline(cin, name2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "\nPlease Enter a Valid Choice.\n";
                    }
                } while (change != "1" && change != "2" && change != "3");

            }


else if (choice == "3")
            {
                cout << "\n" << game.getResults(name1, name2);
            }
            else if (choice != "4")
            {
                cout << "\nPlease Enter a Correct number\n";
            }

        } while (choice!= "4");

        cout << "\nFinal Results are: \n\n"
            << game.getResults(name1, name2);
        cout << "\nThank you for using our program. Hope to see You Again. Bye Bye!!\n";

        system("Pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

my class

```
  #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    #ifndef TICTACTOE_H
    #define TICTACTOE_H



    class TicTacToe
    {
    private:
        const static int SIZE = 3;
        int table[SIZE][SIZE];
        int results[SIZE];
        int winner = 2;

    public:
        TicTacToe();
        void setMove(int , int );
        int chkWin();
        string getResults(string , string );
    };

    #endif
```

here is my methods declaration:

```
   #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include "TicTacToe.h"
    using namespace std;

    TicTacToe::TicTacToe()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            results[i] = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                table[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void TicTacToe::setMove(int place, int player)
    {
        int field = place;

        if (field == 1)
        {
            if (table[0][0] == 0)
            {
                table[0][0] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nYou cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 2)
        {
            if (table[0][1] == 0)
            {
                table[0][1] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 3)
        {
            if (table[0][2] == 0)
            {
                table[0][2] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 4)
        {
            if (table[1][0] == 0)
            {
                table[1][0] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 5)
        {
            if (table[1][1] == 0)
            {
                table[1][1] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 6)
        {
            if (table[1][2] == 0)
            {
                table[1][2] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 7)
        {
            if (table[2][0] == 0)
            {
                table[2][0] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 8)
        {
            if (table[2][1] == 0)
            {
                table[2][1] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
        else if (field == 9)
        {
            if (table[2][2] == 0)
            {
                table[2][2] = player;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You cannot make this move this place is already occupied.Please choose another Field\n";
                cin >> field;
                cin.ignore();
                setMove(field, player);
            }
        }
    }
    int TicTacToe::chkWin()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (table[i][0] == table[i][1] && table[i][0] == table[i][2])
            {
                if (table[i][0] == 1)
                {
                    results[0] += 1;
                    winner = 1;
                }
                else if (table[i][0] == 2)
                {
                    results[2] += 1;
                    winner = -1;
                }

            }

            else if (table[0][i] == table[1][i] && table[0][i] == table[2][i])
            {
                if (table[0][i] == 1)
                {
                    results[0] += 1;
                    winner = 1;
                }
                else if (table[0][i] == 2)
                {
                    results[2] += 1;
                    winner = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        if ((table[0][0] == table[1][1] && table[0][0] == table[2][2]) || (table[0][2] == table[1][1] && table[0][2] == table[2][0]))
        {
            if (table[1][1] == 1)
            {
                results[0] += 1;
                winner = 1;
            }
            else if (table[1][1] == 2)
            {
                results[2] += 1;
                winner = -1;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                {
                    if(table[i][j] == 0)
                    {

                        winner = 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            results[1] += 1;;
            return winner;
        }

    }
    string TicTacToe::getResults(string name1, string name2)
    {
        return ( name1 + " : " + to_string(results[0]) + "\n"
            + "Draws : " + to_string(results[1]) + "\n"
            + name2 + " : " + to_string(results[2]) + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: Could you include the specific errors you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

Compareing functions with integers doesn't make sense. You have to use `()` operator to call functions like this:

```
if (game.chkWin() == 1)
```

instead of

```
if (game.chkWin == 1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro. I damn missed the ().

Answer (score 1):

Poor:

```
  game.setMove(choice_num, 1);
  if (game.chkWin == 1)
  {
      cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
  }
  else if (game.chkWin == -1)
  {
      cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
  }
  else if (game.chkWin == 0)
  {
      cout <<"The Game is a Draw! ";
  }
```

Better:

```
  game.setMove(choice_num, 1);
  switch (game.chkWin()) {
    case 1:
      cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
      break;
    case -1:
      cout << name1 << " has won this Game!";
      break;
    case 0:
      cout <<"The Game is a Draw! ";
      break;
  }
```

The basic problem is using "==" with function game.chkWin, instead of with the *result* of function game.chkWin().

But in cases like this (pun intended) a "switch()" block is probably more readable and better style than multiple "if/else" statements.

'Hope that helps...